# Given an array of positive integers, find shortest subarray whose sum exceeds a threshold

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity

> Given an array of n positive integers and a positive integer s, find the minimal length of a contiguous subarray of which the sum ≥ s. If there isn't one, return 0 instead.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: s = 7, nums = [2,3,1,2,4,3]
>   Output: 2.
>   Explanation: the subarray [4,3] has the minimal length under the problem constraint.

What is the complexity of my solution?

```
class Solution {
    public int minSubArrayLen(int s, int[] nums) {
        int len = nums.length;
        int i=0,j=0;
        int sum=0;
        int res=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        while(i<len && j<len)
        {
            if(sum<s)
            {
            sum = sum+nums[j];
            j++;
            }
            else
            {
               res = Math.min(res,j-i);
               sum = sum-nums[i];
                i++;

            }

        }
        while(sum>=s)
        {

                res = Math.min(res,j-i);
                sum = sum-nums[i];
                i++;

        }

        if(res == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
        return 0;
        else
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity of this solution is `O(n)`, i.e linear time complexity.

Explanation for time complexity to be linear : Here your loops are bounded by the variables `i` and `j` and one of them is always being incremented. So in worst case the loop can run only `2*len` times.

Comment: Thanks, also since s is positive, sum>=s will always terminate before i can be negative. dont you think ? so i<len is not necessary

Comment: My bad, updated the answer.